# How to install scikit-learn for Python3?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, scikit-learn, python-3.6

System: macOS Mojave 10.14.5

I have both Python 2 and Python 3 installed on my Mac and when I try to install scikit-learn using terminal command:

```
pip install scikit-learn
```

It is installed for only Python 2.7 and not Python 3.6 , I wish to install it for both. Is it possible to do the same? And I am not using any virtual environment because I find it really confusing, just in case.

Comment: I think learning how to use [virtual environments](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) will be easier than learning `sklearn`.  Is it also much safer to use a virtual environment for your work rather than using the python installation your OS is relying on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
python3 -m pip install package-name
```

This will install it for python3

Answer (score 4):

Usually pip is version 2, you need to run pip3 to install for python3

There are multiple ways to install pip3, probably best (and easiest) to install along with python3 by downloading the python3 package: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-369/

I however recommend using [conda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/) instead.

Comment: well how do I install pip3?